# Use different styles in different HTML tags using LESS

Tags: css, less

I have the following LESS code:

```
a {
  color: red;
  .action(40%);
}

button {
  color: green;
  .action(60%);
}

.action(@width) {
  // common styles
  background-color: white;
  width: @width; 
  // styles applied to Anchor tag
  // styles applied to Button tag  
}
```

Is it possible in `.action` to apply specific styles when `.action` is used in an `a` tag and others when used in `button` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create a selectors like this.

```
button.action{
/*  Specific styles for button with action class  */
}

a.action{
/*  Specific styles for a tag with action class  */
}
```

A mistake that could be made is using spaces in between the tag and class which in the example below would only select children of the a tag with .action and not the a tag itself.

```
a .action{
/*  Specific styles for a tag with action class  */
}
```